# Textarea inside html ordered list

Tags: html, css

Whenever I stick TextArea inside 'li' tag in ordered list, the number for that 'li' appears next to bottom-left corner of the TextArea instead of top-left. Is there any fix? Can't seem to find it anywhere on the net...

Example:

```
<ol>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>
        <TextArea></TextArea>
    </li>
    <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
```

Will output something like:
[image]
Thanks for help... I seriously don't have nerve to css^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
textarea {
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dugnQ/)

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk I think it defaults to baseline or something, I guess the idea is that's what you'd usually want for an inline-block element. It makes sense for things like labels next to single-line text inputs.